# why doesn't a bash while loop exit when piping to terminated subcommand?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, bash-scripting

Why doesn't the command below exit?  Rather than exit, the loop runs indefinitely.

While I discovered this behavior using a more complex setup, the simplest form of the command reduces to the following.

Does not exit:

```
while /usr/bin/true ; do echo "ok" | cat ; done | exit 1
```

There are no typos above.  Each '|' is a pipe.  The 'exit 1' stands in for another process that ran and exited.

I expect the "exit 1" to cause a SIGPIPE on the while loop (write on a pipe with no reader) and for the loop to break out. But, the loop continues running.

Why doesn't the command stop?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is due to a choice in implementation.

Running the same script on Solaris with `ksh93` produces a different behavior:

```
$ while /usr/bin/true ; do echo "ok" | cat ; done | exit 1
cat: write error [Broken pipe]
```

What triggers the issue is the inner pipeline, without it, the loop exits whatever the shell/OS:

```
$ while /usr/bin/true ; do echo "ok" ; done | exit 1
$
```

`cat` is getting a SIGPIPE signal under bash but the shell is iterating the loop anyway.

```
Process 5659 suspended
[pid 28801] execve("/bin/cat", ["cat"], [/* 63 vars */]) = 0
[pid 28801] --- SIGPIPE (Broken pipe) @ 0 (0) ---
Process 5659 resumed
Process 28801 detached
Process 28800 detached
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
Process 28802 attached
Process 28803 attached
[pid 28803] execve("/bin/cat", ["cat"], [/* 63 vars */]) = 0
Process 5659 suspended
[pid 28803] --- SIGPIPE (Broken pipe) @ 0 (0) ---
Process 5659 resumed
Process 28803 detached
Process 28802 detached
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
Process 28804 attached
Process 28805 attached (waiting for parent)
Process 28805 resumed (parent 5659 ready)
Process 5659 suspended
[pid 28805] execve("/bin/cat", ["cat"], [/* 63 vars */]) = 0
[pid 28805] --- SIGPIPE (Broken pipe) @ 0 (0) ---
Process 5659 resumed
Process 28805 detached
Process 28804 detached
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
```

**Bash** documentation states:

> The shell **waits for all commands** in the pipeline to terminate before returning a value.

**Ksh** documentation states:

> Each command, except possibly the last, is run as a separate process; the shell **waits for the last command** to terminate.

**POSIX** states:

> If the pipeline is not in the background (see Asynchronous Lists), the shell **shall wait for the last command** specified in the pipeline to complete, and **may also wait for all commands** to complete.

Comment: I think it’s not exactly the inner pipeline that triggers the issue, it’s that builtin `echo` ignores SIGPIPE. You can also reproduce the issue by using `env echo` instead of `echo` (to force the actual `echo` binary to be used). (Compare also the output of `{ echo hi; echo $? >&2; } | exit 1` and `{ env echo hi; echo $? >&2; } | exit 1`.)

Answer (score 4):

This issue has bugged me for years.  Thanks to jilliagre for the nudge in the right direction.

Restating the question a little, on my linux box, this quits as expected:

```
while true ; do echo "ok"; done | head
```

But if I add a pipe, it does *not* quit as expected:

```
while true ; do echo "ok" | cat; done | head
```

That frustrated me for years. By considering the answer written by jilliagre, I came up with this wonderful fix:

```
while true ; do echo "ok" | cat || exit; done | head
```

Q.E.D. ...

Well, not quite.  Here's something a bit more complicated:

```
i=0
while true; do
    i=`expr $i + 1`
    echo "$i" | grep '0$' || exit
done | head
```

This doesn't work right. I added the `|| exit` so it knows how to terminate early, but the very first `echo` does not match the `grep` so the loop quits right away.  In this case, you really aren't interested in the exit status of the `grep`.  My work-around is to add another `cat`.  So, here is a contrived script called "tens":

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
while true; do
    i=`expr $i + 1`
    echo "$i" | grep '0$' | cat || exit
done
```

This properly terminates when run as `tens | head`.  Thank God.

Answer (score 0):

Pre requisite: https://askubuntu.com/a/678922

Prefer using a temporary file descriptor and process substitution. That will terminate as per your wish (remember the culprit is `cat` not the `while`).

#### The following will be stuck forever

```sh
while true; do cat /dev/zero; done | head -c 5 | od
```

#### But using process substitution, we can kill the upstream.

```sh
(head -c 5 | od)  < <(while true; do cat /dev/zero; done)
```

---

The answer ends here

---

#### Using hacks (risky, may not work always)

```sh
while cat /dev/zero; do true; done | head -c 5 | od
```

It is upto the audience to understand how the `cat` is receiving the `SIGPIPE` signal, and `true` is not interfering (HINT: or may be it will interfere if finite stream is used instead of `/dev/zero`)

##### Future investigations

```sh
# what about this?
while cat finite_file; do cat finite_file; done | head -c 5 | od
```